# Lock Service across deployments

Tags: google-apps-script, locking

In a scenario of different scripts and/or deployments accessing the same document (Ie: a spreadsheet), the Lock service will prevent access concurrency issues?

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock-service) speaks of "sections of code", but I want to understand if the lock will work for any script accessing the same doc, or only within the code of that specific script deployment.

Comment: LockService does not provide file-level locking. It's a guard against executing specific code sections. Whatever document -- if any -- the script knows about can still be freely modified by whatever / whomever else has the ability to do so.

Comment: That is precisely what I wanted to know, thanks. If you write that as an answer, that is all I need.